# How can I break the with_items loop based on a condition

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-template

I want to break out of the with_items loop based on a condition. That condition for arguments sake is if the stdout of a command is equal to a particular string.

Obviously the example below does not work but this is an idea of what I want to do.

For example:

```
- name: testing loop
  shell: "echo {{ item }}"
  with_items:
     - "one"
     - "two"
     - "three"
  register: shell_command # registering the shell command and it's attributes
  when: shell_command.stdout == "two" # break once the stdout of the run shell command matches the string "two". So it will run twice and break on the second.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In the future, you may want to specify how your example "does not work". Your question is fine, but we get a lot of questions where the entire description of the issue is "it doesn't work", and that tends to bias reviewers against those words.

Comment: @Haem Got that! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This seems not possible at the moment as you can see [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/9782). There exists an untested [hack](https://grokbase.com/t/gg/ansible-project/154htssteb/ansible-loop-break-hack) out there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to abort whole playbook, try this:

```
 - name: testing loop
            shell: "echo {{ item }}"
            with_items:
              - "one"
              - "two"
              - "three"
            register: shell_command
            failed_when: "'two' in shell_command.stdout"
```

Or you can just add `ignore_errors: yes`

Comment: I don't want to abort the whole playbook. I just want to break the loop so I can `continue` on with the rest of the playlook